# How could I clear the textbox in doPost method of the servlet?

Tags: jsp, servlets

I have a page like this:

[image]

How could I clear the username and password in doPost() method of the servlet after pressing the reset button?

Comment: The moment you submit the form and get the response back, those fields will be cleared. You don't have to do anything. Of course, it probably makes more sense to use ajax instead.

Answer (score 0):

set button type to reset `<input type="reset" name="reset" value"Reset">`. You do not need to do anything in servlet.
[demo](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_input_type_reset)